# RTKQ - Select data without hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to select cached data from RTKQ without using the auto-generated query hook, but I'm having trouble understanding the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/usage-without-react-hooks#:%7E:text=selector%20function%20itself!-,With%20React%20hooks,-%2C%20this%20behaviour%20is)

```
const result = api.endpoints.getPosts.select()(state)
const { data, status, error } = result
```

This is how the docs describe how to access the data, but I can't find any references on how to inject the state object "select()(**state**)".

I can't figure out how to access the data if I only call the select?

```
api.endpoints.getPosts.select()
```

Can someone explain me the difference between "select()" and "select()(state)"

Or what is the optimal solution to access the cached data from RTKQ?

Answer (score 3):

The result of `api.endpoints.getPosts.select()` is a **selector function** for the result of using the "getPosts" endpoint without arguments.

Similarly, result of `api.endpoints.getPosts.select({ page: 5 })` is a **selector function** for the result of using the "getPosts" endpoint the argument `{ page: 5 }`.

A selector function is then called as `selector(state)` or passed into `useSelector(selector)`.

If you write that altogether, you end up with `api.endpoints.getPosts.select()(state)`.

Comment: What if we are doing this in mapstateToProps and there are lot of destructure state already ?

Comment: @Probosckie You really should not use any of those selectors in `mapStateToProps`. RTK Query works a *lot* better with hooks in function components. If you do not have an application you cannot upgrade to React 16 (which is over 5 years old) you should definitely use function components and the hooks. Classes are a legacy concept and connect is a legacy api just for compatibility with old class implementations.

Answer (score 1):

@phry

Thank you for your answer! I'm not 100% sure I understood your answer. But it pointed me in a direction that enabled me to get the data.

I ended up creating a selector like the docs.

```
export const selectUser = (state) => userApi.endpoints.getUser.select()(state);
```

and in my function, I referenced it with getting the exported store from configureStore() method

```
const { data } = selectUser(store.getState());
```

But I'm not sure if this is the intended way to do it.